# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutQuart'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, typeerror

The following code is producing an error, and I am not able to understand what is wrong as it works in jsFiddle.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                $({countValue:0}).animate(
                    {countValue:500},
                    {
                        duration: 5000, /* Time for animation in milliseconds */
                        easing:"easeOutQuart",
                        step: function (value) { /* Fired every "frame" */
                            $('span').html(parseInt(value));
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'easeOutQuart'

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you please add the link to the fiddle?

Comment: This is special animation, it's not shipped by default with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

Comment: Might want to link the OP to it and explain what it is for.